# Javascript how to use .includes() when you can hav random capital letters in a string

Tags: javascript

I need to make a program that gets user input string. How to check if a spesific words with .includes() that can have capital leters?

Comment: you can try by converting toUpper() pr toLower() of input i guess.. but of you can add with example exactly what you need it will help us help u :)

Comment: the question is not clear, you want to check if the string contains a certain word, and if this word have capital letters? or you want to match that word case insensitive ?

Comment: **Specific words** means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way is to get rid of the capital letters

```
inputString.toLowerCase().includes(str)
```

Otherwise you would need an alternative solution such as a regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

[according to MDN String.includes() specifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

> The includes() method is case sensitive. For example, the following expression returns false:
>
> 'Blue Whale'.includes('blue'); // returns false

so if you want to use String.includes() and you want to check for variable data you should use the solution of converting the string to lowercase before calling .includes() .

if what you mean by specific word is that it is always the same word you want to check for (or string, it could have spaces), you have the option of regular expression:

```
// using the i flag here you check for the word multycaseworld case insensitively
var reggex = /\bmultycaseworld\b/i   // adding \b to match word boundary (avoiding cat to match both cat and caterpillar)
var string = 'some string with MulTyCaseWorld'

var result = string.match(reggex)
//result will hold an array with the match so if result.length > 0 then you have a match
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0gc5rpdv/3/

Comment: var reggex = /\bmultycaseworld\b/i 
Otherwise you would match parts of words as well (unless that's what you want of course)

Comment: good point, with a simpler word it could be an issue. I updated my solution